# Populate a Drop Down List with Unique Values from a list

Tags: development, asp.net

I have got a list with names of workers. How could I populate a DropDownList with unique values (ie: avoid duplicate) from the list? If the list contains duplicate values I need to avoid inserting the same value multiple times in the dropdown.

Here is my current code:

```
SPList kontraktyList = witryna.Lists["Urlopy_prac"];
SPQuery kontraktyQuery = new SPQuery();
kontraktyQuery.Query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='nazwisko'/></OrderBy></Query>";
SPListItemCollection kontraktyGrupa = kontraktyList.GetItems(kontraktyQuery);

foreach (SPListItem kontraktyListItem in kontraktyGrupa)
{
    DropDownList4.Items.Add(kontraktyListItem["nazwisko"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hi Grzegorz - I don't think you want `<Query>` in your Query... whenever I put that in my CAML it stops it working and just returns all results without any mind paid to the query.

Comment: I want only take one field from the External List. How Would it be fasters, and oriented Ascending ? Only one field, but ordered Ascending

Comment: If you want your CAML query to return only 1 field, please use: `kontraktyQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='nazwisko'/>";`. No sense to use the `.Query` property to restrict the number of fields to be returned. The `.Query` property is for `<Where/>` and `<OrderBy/>` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your `foreach` like this:

```
foreach (string kontraktyListText in kontraktyGrupagreat.Cast<SPListItem>().Select<SPListItem,string>(source => source["nazwisko"] as string).Distinct())
{
    DropDownList4.Items.Add(kontraktyListText);
}
```

Please try it out and tell me if it worked.

Cheers!

Comment: It's no worked on my Code :( Please help. Meybe in element it should be ?

Comment: Want to go to chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6545/discussion-between-diptarag-and-grzegorz-z

Comment: I'm on chat :) :)

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I made a stupid mistake. I have edited my response.

Comment: Now its a great solution :)